# Bash scripting unexpected operator

Tags: bash, shell

I'm writing script for git hook and have trouble with `if` statement inside `while`.

File:

```
#!/bin/sh
while read oldrev newref ref
do
    branch=$(git rev-parse --symbolic --abbrev-ref $ref)

    if [ "a"  == "a" ]
    then
        echo "Condition work"
    fi

    echo "$branch"
done
```

Error:

```
hooks/post-receive: 6: [: a: unexpected operator
```

I'll try with variables, double quotes but `if` doesn't work. What kind of error is here?

Thanks

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`if [ "a" == "a" ]` should be `if [ "a" = "a" ]`.

`bash` accepts `==` instead of `=`, but your `/bin/sh` probably isn't bash.

So either change the `==` to `=`, or your shebang to `#!/bin/bash`